# My site can be called via localhost:8080/Mysite/index.html but not via localhost/Mysite/index.html

Tags: apache, localhost

I´m using Apache-Server. The configuration of proxy pass for localhost is like this. Is there something wrong?

```
ProxyVia On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /error !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/


 <Proxy http://localhost:8080/Mysite*>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from localhost
 </Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the order "deny, allow", it works.